# Binding IsPaneOpen to bool property trouble

Tags: c#, mvvm, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to deal with mvvm logic in my Universal Windows Platform app. Everything works fine with static bindings and observableCollections, but I got stuck with binding Button `Click` event to bool property, that in theory should affect on `SplitView`'s `IsPaneOpen` state. At first look everything looks fine and builds without any warning, but somehow it fails to make Property changes observable. 
Here's my MainPageViewModel.cs:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return "String!"; // it works
        }
    }

    private bool _isPaneOpen; // false

    public bool isPaneOpen // x:Bind to SplitViews's "IsPaneOpen" property
    {
        get { return _isPaneOpen; } // false
        set
        {
            if (value != this._isPaneOpen)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(_isPaneOpen); // false
                _isPaneOpen = value; // false -> true
                Debug.WriteLine(_isPaneOpen); // true
                this.OnPropertyChanged("isPaneOpen"); // and nothing happended...
            }  
        }
    }

    public void changePaneState() // x:Bind to button
    {
        isPaneOpen = !isPaneOpen; // true
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the mainPage.xaml:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0">
                <Button Background="#eee" Name="Back" Height="50" Width="50" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="22" Content="&#xE0D5;" Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.changePaneState}"/>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Margin="10 0 0 0"
                           Name="DebugTextBlock" FontSize="18" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Title}"
                           FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <SplitView Name="SideBar" IsPaneOpen="{x:Bind ViewModel.isPaneOpen}" Style="{StaticResource SplitViewStyle}">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <Grid>
```

Any ideas what might go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mode should be `TwoWay`, since you are making change in Viewmodel,to reflect in Ui you should have given `TwoWay` Mode

```
IsPaneOpen="{x:Bind ViewModel.isPaneOpen,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: Working perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

x:Bind mode is by default **OneTime** (classic binding is OneWay). So you need to explicitly set the binding mode to OneWay or TwoWay.

```
IsPaneOpen="{x:Bind ViewModel.isPaneOpen,Mode=OneWay}"
```